# JQuery: appendTo

Tags: jquery

Еще раз приветствую.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#add").click(function() {
        $('<p><input type="text" placeholder="Текст"><a href="#" id="remove">Удалить</a></p>').appendTo($("#test"));
    });
    $("#remove").click(function() {
        alert("removed");
    });
});
```

*#remove не выполняется, подскажите пожалуйста, что не так?*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы  генерирует элемент с `id`? Возможно это происходит несколько раз, лучше  используйте вот такую конструкцию:

```
$(function () {
    $("#add").click(function () {
        var $remove = $('<a href="#">Удалить</a></p>');
        $('<p>').append('<input type="text" placeholder="Текст">').append($remove).appendTo($("#test"));
        $remove.click(function () {
            alert("removed");
            return false;
        });
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/6pFPP/

и у вас там скобочки были неправильно расставлены, исправил.

Comment: Спасибо, но не выполняется все равно.

Comment: исправил ответ

Comment: Благодарю!

Comment: @eicto, готово.

Answer (score 1):

Код `$('#remove')` срабатывает до того как обновилась DOM модель. Вариантов два:
Или вешайте обработчик на созданный элемент:

```
...
$("#add").click(function() {
        var x = $('<p><input type="text" placeholder="Текст"><a href="#" id="remove">Удалить</a></p>');x.appendTo($("#test"));x.find('#remove').click(...);
    });
...
```

или выполняйте код после добавления:

```
...
$("#add").click(function() {
        $('<p><input type="text" placeholder="Текст"><a href="#" id="remove">Удалить</a></p>').appendTo($("#test"));
    $("#remove").click(function() {
        alert("removed");
    });
    });
...
```

или использовать on :

```
...
    $("#remove").on('click',function() {
        alert("removed");
    });
...
```

Comment: И Вам спасибо за подробный ответ!